# openlayers map inside a dojo dialog

Tags: openlayers-2, wms, dojo

My application is currently displaying some search results in a dojo grid inside a dialog. I've been asked to embed a map inside the dialog but am struggling to do so. Has anyone done this?

I've got a simple map inside a jsp and have tried

```
dialog.set("href","url_for_my.jsp")
```

Also tried putting a button on the page to with map.render("mapdiv") after the dialog is displayed. Dialog.refresh() has no effect. There are no errors and no requests made for map tiles.

Can anyone suggest a better way of displaying a map in a popup?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can confirm you it is perfectly possible to put OpenLayers map within a Dojo's dialog widget.

What you can try to do is create in a declarative way a contentPane with an OpenLayers map. Then create the dialog and set the contenPane as the dialog's content.

Cheers.

Comment: Neil, thanks for the tip. I can confirm that approach works. var divMap = document.getElementById("auditMap");
dialog.set("content", divMap)